# Symfony Base64_encode on pdf in response

Tags: symfony, pdf, base64, mime-types

I want to base64_encode a pdf file before returning it to the client.

Here is what I do

```
$response = $event->getResponse();
$response->headers->remove('Content-Disposition');

$response->setContent(
    $response->headers->get('Content-Type')
    . ';base64,'
    . base64_encode($response->getContent())
);

$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
```

The pdf that I get in a browser when I put `data:<base64_encoded_string>` doesn't have any value, but the whole skeleton/css is ok.

If I do

```
$response = $event->getResponse();
$response->headers->remove('Content-Disposition');

$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
```

I do get a valid pdf file with all the values.

Is it possible that the base64_encoding is breaking something ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you just want to return a base64-encoded string? Why can't you just `return new Response(base64_encode($file))`?

Comment: Because I'm not in a controller, but in an eventSubscriber, so I need to modify the current Response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, I had a sub-request, so its content was also base64 encoded, that's why the master request's content was broken.